# Ripple-эффект на android SDK16

Tags: android, android-sdk

В Android sdk21 есть класс `RippleDrawable`, который позволяет делать приятные Ripple-эффекты. Есть ли нечто подобное для SDK16, быть может какой-то сторонний инструмент?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть несколько кастомных реализаций:

https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect
https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple
https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView
https://github.com/ozodrukh/RippleDrawable
https://github.com/keithellis/MaterialWidget

Comment: Спасибо огромное, буду смотреть)